# Intellij Highlighting Error with No Errors

Tags: intellij-idea, dart, flutter

If I use InelliJ on my desktop, I get no errors with no highlights, but if I use it on my mac, I get highlighted errors all over the place. But if I go to dart analysis on my mac, it still shows 0 red errors.

[image]

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.8.2, on Mac OS X 10.14 18A391, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.8.2 at /Users/alexjee/flutter
    • Framework revision 5ab9e70727 (4 weeks ago), 2018-09-07 12:33:05 -0700
    • Engine revision 58a1894a1c
    • Dart version 2.1.0-dev.3.1.flutter-760a9690c2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alexjee/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.0, Build version 10A255
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 28.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.2.4)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 29.0.4
    • Dart plugin version 182.4505.50

[✓] VS Code (version 1.27.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.19.0

[!] Connected devices
    ! No devices available
```

Comment: Please add the output of `flutter doctor -v` from your Mac as text to your question.

Comment: I think you don't have the Flutter plugin installed in IntelliJ or not specified the SDK path in the plugin settings.

Comment: Try running `flutter clean` in the project directory.

Comment: I have the flutter plugin installed, but I can't find it when I search in plugins when I try to add an IntelliJ platform plugin SDK. I already tried flutter clean.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the computer?

Comment: Still having the same issues.

Comment: Have you tried running "File | Invalidate Caches"?

Comment: Yeah, it still has the same issue. It doesn't make any sense. I have the same exact settings and everything on my desktop and it doesn't have this issue...